# How to add columns dynamically as per ajax call result in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am new to datatables. I have a table with 6 columns that is constructed using datatbles. Then I wantto add some columns in the table dynamicaly based on data i got in ajax call. I dont know how i can add columns in datatable dynamically based on data we got in ajax call. If I got a particluar data in ajax call result, then i need to add that column dynamically in the table else not. Like this I have to add all ajax call data in the table dyanmicaly apart from the table headings

Comment: What you have tried still now?

Comment: construct table with 6 columns using data tables. Trying to add column in table if i particular data is available in Ajax call.Any help is much appreciated. Thanks